# Get input values from JComboBox

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

How can I get the input for an editable `JComboBox`.  When user gives an input to the combo how I can get the input text from it?

Comment: See actually i need to get input through Jcombo. I know how to deal with the Getselecteditem. but it doesn't work; 
(the input will be string;)

Comment: And looking further you may have found [`getEditor()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#getEditor%28%29`)

Comment: jComboBox2.getEditor().toString().toUpperCase(); Doesn't Work..! :(

Comment: @AndrewThompson +1 on the link of 'What have you tried?'!

Comment: @Fido  Newbies should book-mark it, and check it before asking a question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to get the edited text from the combobox editor via [`combo.getEditor().getItem()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ComboBoxEditor.html#getItem%28%29).

Answer (score 4):

If you need the text that is selected on a `JComboBox` and you are sure it's a `String` and not any other object, just use something like `String text = (String)myCombobox.getSelectedItem()`. 
If the thing you have in your `Model` is other than a `String`, then you need to cast it to the appropriate class, and then use the `toString()` method of that object.
If you need more help, you should paste a bit of your code, at least declaration and inicialization of your `JComboBox`...

Answer (score 1):

Just have a look at the oracle tutorial. They do explain how to handle the common swing components http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html